# addEventListener only triggers for first event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I am wondering why the following does work:

```
//maak variabelen aan
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var show = 100;
        var hide = 99;

    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        if (video.currentTime >=show){
            showPlaceHolder();
        }

        if (video.currentTime <=hide){
            hidePlaceHolder();
        }
            }, false);
```

But for the following code only the first event triggers? :

```
var bvideo = document.getElementById('background');
var boombegin = 0;
var boomeind = 7;
var autoeind = 13;
var wolkbegin = 13;
var wolkeind = 19;

   bvideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        if (bvideo.currentTime <=boombegin){
            document.getElementById('boom').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('wolk').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('car').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

        if (bvideo.currentTime >=boomeind){
            document.getElementById('boom').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('car').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        if (bvideo.currentTime >=autoeind){
            document.getElementById('car').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

        if (bvideo.currentTime >= wolkbegin){
            document.getElementById('wolk').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        if (bvideo.currentTime >= wolkeind){
            document.getElementById('wolk').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }, false);
```

Is there anyone who knows why only the first event is being triggered?

I have tried the following for the addEventListener:
Seconds,
MS,
setting alerts to check which events fired (only the first one does)

Comment: why don't you just combine the two functions into one?

Comment: I can't, as there's an event listener for 2 seperate video's, I have however removed duplicates in the code, but it still doesn't work.. the first image to become visible is visible, others invisible but the second event never triggers?

Comment: can you make this into a fiddle so that I can help you further?

Comment: The issue has been resolved, however I want to thank you for your advice, it was a simple mistake I overlooked, I will accept my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to edit the following lines:
from:

```
  if (video.currentTime >= wolkeind){
```

to:

```
if (bvideo.currentTime >= wolkeind){
```

so it checked for the wrong event, thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

The second element seems like a slideshow, does the current time update on the 2nd one?

also your 2nd if check will always evaluate true after the second call.

Comment: The issue has been fixed, thank you for your reply though, i just forgot to edit 'video' to 'bvideo' b standing for 'background'